# Resolving module name conflicts, need to get at ORD_MAP signature

Tags: sml, smlnj

I'm working on a relatively large SML codebase. It was originally written to compile with MLton, but I'm now working with it under SML/NJ. I need to use `RedBlackMapFn`, which is defined in `smlnj-lib.cm`. However, I get an error:

```
elaborate/elaborate-bomenv.fun:9.20-9.27 Error: unbound signature: ORD_KEY
elaborate/elaborate-bomenv.fun:14.21-14.40 Error: unbound functor: RedBlackMapFn
elaborate/elaborate-bomenv.fun:32.20-32.27 Error: unbound signature: ORD_KEY
elaborate/elaborate-bomenv.fun:37.21-37.40 Error: unbound functor: RedBlackMapFn
```

So I assume that `smlnj-lib.cm` is not being pulled by CM. In an effort to fix this, I added `$/smlnj-lib.cm` to the `sources.cm` file in the directory that I'm working in. This causes a separate issue:

```
elaborate/sources.cm:25.1-25.18 Error: structure Random imported from $SMLNJ-LIB/Util/smlnj-lib.cm@243997(random.sml) and also from ./(sources.cm):lib/(sources.cm):basic/(sources.cm):random.sml
elaborate/sources.cm:25.1-25.18 Error: structure Queue imported from $SMLNJ-LIB/Util/smlnj-lib.cm@436143(queue.sml) and also from ./(sources.cm):lib/(sources.cm):basic/(sources.cm):two-list-queue.sml
```

No dice. I tried removing the `Random` structure that's coming from `./(sources.cm):lib/(sources.cm):basic/(sources.cm):random.sml`, but it appears that it isn't equivalent to the one defined in the standard library, so I can't just substitute one for the other.

I'd like to use something like Python's `import ... from ... as ...` 
mechanism to give a new name to the `Random` that's coming from the standard library, but CM's [documentation](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/CM/new.pdf) doesn't offer any hints as to how I'd go about that.

How can I resolve a module naming conflict across multiple SML files?

Comment: @newacct Not true, it looks like CM doesn't pull in `$/smlnj-lib.cm` if it would cause a naming conflict (like it is for me). I can get at `RedBlackMapFn` in other SML code that I've written, but not in this project.

Comment: Maybe a function that wraps `RedBlackMapFn` in a separately compiled module implementing a signature that hides the second declaration of `random`? *Disclaimer: There's a reason this is a comment and not an answer.*

Comment: @benrudgers I ended up splitting the file that needed `RedBlackMapFn` off into a separate `.cm` file and that worked. It's kind of ugly though. It would be nice to know if there's a better way.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Have you considered posting it as an answer?

Comment: @benrudgers I was hoping someone else had a better idea, but sure, I'll post it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up splitting off the problematic file in to a separate `.cm`. The problem file here is `elaborate-bomenv.{sig, fun}`. The `.cm` file for this directory is `sources.cm`, which caused errors when it looked like:

```
Group
...
is

$/basis.cm
...
elaborate-bomenv.fun
elaborate-bomenv.sig
...
```

So instead, I made an `elaborate-bomenv-sources.cm` that looks like:

```
Group

signature ELABORATE_BOMENV
functor BOMEnv

is

$/smlnj-lib.cm
...
elaborate-bomenv.sig
elaborate-bomenv.fun
```

and changed the original `sources.cm` to read:

```
Group
...
is

$/basis.cm
...
./elaborate-bomenv-sources.cm
...
```

Which is ugly, but it works.